# Physical Server Centos "Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown"

Tags: linux, server, centos

I restarted the server via plesk panel. But it did not reopen. When I looked at the server, I saw this error. I am sharing the screenshot. I could not find a solution!

[image]

Comment: There is no error durring your boot (all steps are labeled with OK) and UTMP is just tool for finding logged in users. For how long did server stayed in this state?

Comment: The server has been in this state for about 1 hour

Comment: Did some lookups and find [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391612/boot-stopped-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes-headless-s). I know that mentioned system is different but symptom is same.

Comment: I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451348/ubuntu-boot-hangs-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-boot-shutdown) too. But these solutions didn't work.

Comment: Ok, long way then. Start system in rescue mode and search `/var/log/messages` for any trace of error or explanation about what wrong is happening durring boot

Comment: Thank you for your help. We format the server and we will install it with backup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228621/discussion-between-facty-and-muhammed-alper-uslu).